# Rails not running after Ruby update (possibly RVM related)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, bundler

I resorted to upgrading Ruby from 2.3.0 to 2.3.1 because of a really weird error I was getting and not being able to even come close to finding more info around google/SO.

Now after trying to figure this out I am getting this error whenever I try to run the project, or run bundle or rails in bash

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)

from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:127:in `rescue in require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.16.0/exe/bundle:10:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I have already tried reinstalling Ruby, RVM, bundler, but the error persists. I cannot find much info on that specific error around the web so I hope someone can help me troubleshoot this through here. Let me know if there are any specific logs I can provide and I will happily add more info.

EDIT:
I just noticed the path is `...ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/ 2.3.0 ...` (the difference of 2.3.1 and 2.3.0)
When I upgraded to 2.3.1 I uninstalled previous versions. Could that be an issue since the error comes from a path that refers to a non-existing version of ruby?

Comment: Have you run `gem install bundler`?

Comment: @TomAranda Yes I did. It reports:
`Successfully installed bundler-1.16.0`
`1 gem installed`

but I still get the exact same error.

Comment: You might try using `rvm implode` to uninstall rvm and run `rm -rf /usr/loca/rvm`.  That will completely wipe out all of your rvm files.  You can then reinstall rvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why all this happened and what was wrong with the bundler, but what ended up fixing it for me was this command:

`gem update --system`